# TestRail - Test runs being locked out

Tags: test-management

My project have been experiencing the following issue:

During execution of a test run we aretrying to update some test steps.
The system produced a pop up box saying 'could no longer edit the test step'.
On closing the popup box, we attempted to edit the test step again and the same message appeared.

Hitting F5 to refresh the browser causes the ‘edit’ button on the test run to disappear.

The test run was initially created yesterday at 10.37am (30/01/2017) and this issue occurred at almost exactly 24hrs later.

We've experienced a similar issue on another case where the edit button seems to have disappeared for no reason.

We haven't reassigned the case to another tester or anything of that nature, so we're kind of stumped!

Does anyone know if TestRail gives you 24hrs after starting a test before it locks you out?
Or is there some setting I don't know about?

Please note that I don't have admin access to TestRail, so can't check settings myself. It's controlled centrally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And answering my own question....

I managed to speak to the system administrator for our TestRail system and he confirmed that there is a setting in the system which locks an active test run after 24 hours.

They are thinking of removing it!

Comment: Since you answered your own question, can you accept it as the answer? It doesn't give you points but it marks the question as solved.

Comment: Will accept tomorrow, when the system allows me to. :)